# How to save multiple files to documents directory and retrieve them properly

Tags: ios, arrays, file, nsdocumentdirectory

I would like to save multiple images/videos to the documents directory for later use and I get the gist of how to save a single one, but I don't know how to save multiple images and retrieve them. How would I change this code to retrieve all the objects saved in the directory where the file is located? I am using two view controllers to do this.

Here is the code for saving the image:

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:moviePath];     
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"]; //Add the file name
[videoData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file
```

Here is the code for retrieving the image:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
```

The only problem with the code is this would only get the image at the 0th position and I would like to get all the positions.

Comment: If you can do it for one file, you can do it for multiple files use a simple `for`...

Answer (score 0):

You need to give each file a unique name.

Then keep track of the names in some manner.

You can also get a list of the files in the directory with the  `NSFileNamager` method `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:`.

Answer (score 0):

here is my code to save multiple image in array

```
  let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        var array  = NSMutableArray()   
        let i = Int(arc4random())

                    let str = String(i).appending(".png")



                    array.insert(str, at: 0)
                    defaults.set(array, forKey: "me")
                    defaults.synchronize()
                    let fileManager = FileManager.default
                    let paths = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent(str)

                    print(paths)

                    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(YourImage)
                    fileManager.createFile(atPath: paths as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

And for retrieving the image

```
 let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
        let nsUserDomainMask    = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
           let array1 = defaults.value(forKey: "me") as? NSArray as Array?
    let paths               = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)
        if let dirPath          = paths.first
        {

        let strPic = (array1?[indexPath.row] as! String)
           imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent(strPic! as String) as NSURL




            cell.imgView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path!)
```